Backfill given values based on day number of the year for given set of dates
I am trying to write a Python code to automate my work. I have pandas dataframe with date, values & id associated to it. It am trying to backfill values to individual 365 days based on dates & ids given. Below it shows input and output formats.

I started with this but couldn't go far -
data['dayofyear'] = data['Date'].dt.dayofyear

Please [edit] your post data as text, not image. See [ask] for tips and good practices.

You haven't made it totally clear where you want to get the missing values from in the values column, but if you want to backfill using the values from the later dates then this would work:
dates= pd.Index([pd.Timestamp("2023-12-27"),pd.Timestamp("2023-12-29"),pd.Timestamp("2024-01-03")])
values=pd.Series([np.nan,100,300], dates)
values.asfreq('D').fillna(method='bfill')


Thank you, there are no missing values but I have more than 10k rows with all the columns filled, so I am looking for more generic solution. above provides me direction to try to do that.

Glad to hear it! Since you found it helpful, can you upvote and/or accept my answer? Thank you!
